# Promise performance issue. Reading files too slow

Tags: node.js, io, promise, bluebird

Im using promises to read 10000+ files in the hard drive and find a number at an exact position. Im using glob to return the filenames and for each file found i run the method readFile (readFile returns as promisse). When all files are processed i can continue my work.

```
function readFilesGlob(globPath,options,progressCallback){
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){

      glob(globPath, options, function (err, files) {
        var readPromisses=[];
        for(var id in files){
          readPromisses.push(readFile(files[id]));
        }

        Promise.all(readPromisses).then(
          function(filesContents){
            fulfill(filesContents)
          }
        ); 

      });
    });
  }
```

all promises only complete when everything is done, making it unable to show progress of processing

```
function readFilesGlob(globPath,options,progressCallback){
    return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){

      glob(globPath, options, function (err, files) {
        var readPromisses=[];
        for(var id in files){
          readFile(files[id]).then(function(data){
            //everything shows at the same time, like i was using the Promise.all
            console.log(data)
          })
        }
        //just testing the speed of the return in the console.log above
        fulfill();

      });
    });
```

The problem is. It is too slow and i only have a return several minutes later (or when i get out of memory)

Im thintking that im using promises wrong. Can someone give me an more performatic example to read a list of files with promises?

Comment: `Promise.all` waits until every file is read and your timeout example just reads one file. IMO your performance issue is not about the promises but about reading lots of files simultaneously

Comment: thanks, the timeout was realling making me use only the last promise. I have made another test not using Promise.all. Just want to console.log the files loaded. they only list when everything loads

Comment: I notice that you're reading 10000+ files, and with `Promise.all` 1000+ promises isn't a good way to implement though it cost not only i/o but also CPU, RAM for that. IMO, it's better if limit the number of files reading as the same time. e.g : 500 files at a time or 1000. I think it could improve the speed, also save the resource than read it all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a excellent solution for the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) package!

Checkout the `each` function: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each

**Example:**

```
// assuming openFiles is an array of file names
async.each(openFiles, function(file, callback) {

    // Perform operation on file here.
    console.log('Processing file ' + file);

    if( file.length > 32 ) {
      console.log('This file name is too long');
      callback('File name too long');
    } else {
      // Do work to process file here
      console.log('File processed');
      callback();
    }
}, function(err) {
    // if any of the file processing produced an error, err would equal that error
    if( err ) {
      // One of the iterations produced an error.
      // All processing will now stop.
      console.log('A file failed to process');
    } else {
      console.log('All files have been processed successfully');
    }
});
```

I use the async package in almost all my projects, it's fast and has loads of features <3

**Alternative: Use a queue system**

Setup a queue system, one I worked with is [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue), this way you can also checkout the progress on your 'tasks'

Comment: `async.each` won't solve the issue, as that will also process all files in parallel. Instead, use something like [`eachLimit`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit).

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your for loop you would need something like this

```
readPromisses.push(
   new Promise( function(y,n) { readFile(files[id]); y();} )
)
```

Then `readFile` will be called when the `Promise` is begin executed async.
This is just a suggestion, I haven't tested this so you may will have to tweak it a bit.

Here is a skeleton, perhaps that will help

```
var firstCall  = new Promise((y, n) => setTimeout( () =>  y(Math.random()), 500 ));

var secondCall = (arg) => {
    return new Promise((y, n) => setTimeout( () =>  y(Math.random() + ' ' +  arg), 200 ));
}

var rejectCall = () => new Promise((y, n) => setTimeout( () =>  n(true), 400 ));

Promise.all([
    firstCall,
    secondCall('withArg'),
]).then( (data) => {
    console.log( 'ALL: First Call result:',  data[0]);
    console.log( 'ALL: Second Call result:', data[1]);
}).catch( (err) => {
    console.log( 'Promise.all caught reject or error:', err);
});
```

Comment: tried. Still only doing everything in the end. Im wondering if it is something related to I/O?

Comment: ah, I think the issue might be in your `.then` clause.  To the best of my understanding `.then` will receive an array of results in the order they were called. Let me find the skeleton I use for this.

Answer (score 1):

If  I/O is the problem, you could split your 'files' array into chunks, and chain those chunks.

```
chunks.reduce((result, chunk) => {
   return Promise.all(chunk.map(file=> promiseRead(file))
   .then(results => dealWithChunkResults(results)
}, Promise.resolve())
```